# Replace whole line with a string using Perl

Tags: perl, file

I need to replace a whole line in a text file with a string i've in a variable. My attempt at the code is as below but i get nothing. Anything missing?

```
 my @a;
 $ldir= "/project/";
 $RESULTS_FILE = $ldir.'/'.'out.html';
 open OUT, "<", $RESULTS_FILE or die "Could not open results file:$!";
        while ($ln=<OUT>)
        {
                chomp($ln);
                for my $str (@stream_name)
                {
                        if ( $ln =~ m/$str/ )
                        {
                                $str =~ s/(.)/$1: NOT-RUN/g;

                        }
                }
                push @a, $str;
                #push @a, $ln;
        }
        open F, ">results.html" || die "$!";
        print "\n\n\nContents of Array is:@a\n\n\n";
        for my $e (@a)
        {
                print F "$e\n";
        }
        close F;
```

Comment: How did `@stream_name` get set?  Don't leave out important parts of the code!

Comment: provide sample data to work with.

Comment: Here is the data: <br><br><a><b><font color=blue>Streams:</font></b></a><br>=====================================================<br> dif6.ts :    <a><b><font color=green>PASS</font></b></a><br><br><br><a><b><font color=blue>A Streams:</font></b></a><br>=====================================================<br> O-6.wma :  <a><b><font color=green>PASS</font></b></a><br>=====================================================<br> te_2.wma :     <a><b><font color=green>PASS</font></b></a><br>=====================================================<br>===========================<br></body></html>

Comment: The above is data of out.html. Whole data is a single line. @stream_name values are: O-6.wma and te_2.wma

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
push @a, $str;
```

Is outside of the `for` loop.  You should really `use strict` so that these errors are caught for you and you don't have to struggle so much.

Comment: No its not working. I'm getting only the last line to be printed after placing inside for loop.

Comment: Please include code that is completely runnable, otherwise we're just grasping at straws and could go back and forth here for a while.